# Is it possible to use hbase to store json documents and query with phoenix?

Tags: json, hadoop, hbase, hdfs, apache-phoenix

I am trying to figure out a solution for our data problem. Basically, we:

- have event data on a per-user basis that streams into our system
- but we want to be able to aggregate several users together when it is clear that they are the same person (so we propose to store the event data in hbase so that we can delete and update rows)
- the data is in the form of json documents
- we would like to be able to run sql-like queries on the data, that, for example, retrieve all the rows whose json document has a key of 'page-visited' and a value of 'homepage'. In other words we want to be able to build queries that are looking at the individual keys and value of the json documents.

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to:

- store this data in hbase (I think it should be possible/easy)
- query it with phoenix in some way (only just started looking at phoenix, but seems like it might be possible to define a column as of type 'json' and maybe it has some json functions - though I didn't find any yet)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems like http://drill.apache.org/ might do what I need, querying hbase directly?